# Do ORM frameworks like hibernate implement any kind of rowmapper while iterating over a result set?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Do ORM frameworks like hibernate implement any kind of rowmapper while iterating over a result set? If not implementing a row mapper, do they at least iterate the resultset while creating  a list of entities or they directly get list of entities as resultset? i.e., internal working of the `createQuery("from Employee").getResultlist();`

And if we use a native query does it directly return the result set or iterate over the result set and return a list of object arrays i.e., `List<Object[]>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if Hibernate is using some kind of object oriented extension when querying: Hibernate works with a lot of databases, it can't use OO vendor extensions because those won't be standardized.

If you look at annotations or mappings for an entity, those tell what column each property is mapped to. So yes, it does have row-mapping functionality where it generates a query, maps the columns to properties, and populates entities from it.

You can see the SQL Hibernate generates by setting the log level for the logger org.hibernate.sql to DEBUG.